# Concatenate a new string at the beginning of an existing string

Tags: java, string-concatenation

i want to concatenate a new string to the start of an existing string, for example, 
the current string="" and i want always to concatenate the new string to start of my old string:

```
  String msg="Java One",temp;
 for(int i=msg.length()-2;i>0;i--){
```

here i make a loop starting from the end of msg after the end finishes temp should contains "Java One" but in this order

```
 e
 ne
 one
 a one
 va one 
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want always to concatenate the new string to start of my old string

This is very simple, but not very efficient:

```
String oldString = "";
for (...) {
    // Prepare your new string
    String newString = ... ;
    // Add the new string at the beginning of the old string
    oldString = newString + oldString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#substring(int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to get different substrings in each iteration.

```
for(int i=msg.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
    System.out.println(msg.substring(i,msg.length()));
}
```

Of course you can store each generated substring and do what you wish with it.

Note that this approach is likely to be more efficient, because though new `String` objects will be created, it is likely to use the same underlying `char[]` object for all of them.

---

Also note that we are iterating from `msg.length()-1` (and not -2, as the original code in the question) and while `i >= 0` (and not `i > 0`, as in the original question)